# How to animate a number as it increases

Tags: flutter, animation, dart

I have a `Card` that has a number set by a model. I would like the number to gradually increment from 0 to the model's value.

```
return Card(
  child: Text("${model.price.toStringAsPrecision(2)}",
      style: GoogleFonts.robotoSlab().copyWith(
          fontSize: 12, color: stockColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
);
```

How can I add the animation to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/mccounting_text 
You can set `begin` to 0 and `end` to `model.price` and `duration` 
For demo purpose, I set `duration` to 10 seconds 
code snippet

```
Card(
      child: McCountingText(
          begin: 0,
          end: _price,
          precision: 2,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
          duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
          curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
        ))
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mccounting_text/mccounting_text.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _price = 99.12;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
                child: McCountingText(
              begin: 0,
              end: _price,
              precision: 2,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
              curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but mccounting lib not on null safety